# Можно ли через python управлять своим дискорд аккаунтом чтобы автоматизировать какие нибудь действия?

Tags: python, discord.py

Хочу через python сделать очистку друзей в своем аккаунте дискорда,вопрос- возможно ли это а то я нашел информацию только по ботам для серверов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Технически можно, согласно TOS запрещено. Так что если что, enjoy your ban ;)

Как сделать технически -- очень просто. Тебе нужен токен своего аккаунта, ты можешь его найти в local storage в хроме (в firefox так и не понял как, его там нету). Дальше пишешь его вместо токена бота и прописываешь в `run` `bot=False`:

```
bot.run(token, bot=False) # токен из local storage, а не бота
```

Готово!

Answer (score 1):

Запрещено TOS, ранее была реализация в discordpy - > remove_friend(),
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.remove_friend